# What is computational complexity of Monte-Carlo sampling?

Tags: sampling, monte-carlo, error, resampling, particle-filter

Monte-Carlo method is basically used to integrate multivariate functions.
If we use deterministic methods (e.g. Riemann integration), estimation error has an order of $O(m^{-\frac{1}{n}})$, where $m$ - a number of points where we evaluate the function, $n$ - a number of dimensions.
Therefore a number of calculations required to achieve the same accuracy grows exponentially on the dimensionality $n$.

In Monte-Carlo method estimation error has an order of $O(m^{-\frac{1}{2}})$ and doesn’t depend on n. That’s the main advantage of this method.

However, sampling from multivariate distribution requires some computational efforts and I want to find out how sampling computational complexity depends on the number of dimensions. As if sampling is not cost effective this method wouldn’t outperform Riemann integration despite error independence on $n$. My best guess is that sampling complexity has an order of $O(n)$.

I'd be very thankful if you could give some explanations on this question.

Comment: You mean complexity for any algorithm, for any problem..? It is like you asked what is the computational complexity of optimization algorithms in general...

Comment: As Tim suggested, you're not going to get a general answer to the question. However, MC is generally used when integration is intractable.

Comment: @conjectures Monte Carlo algorithm is used for intractable problems as it's more computationally efficient than deterministic algorithms. We can notice that error order in Monte-Carlo method is independent of n. But who knows, maybe sampling from multivariate distribution is so complex that nullifies the advantage of this independence.  
How can I show that it doesn't happen and Monte-Carlo still outperforms deterministic algorithms?

Comment: What deterministic algorithm are you thinking of that does the same thing as monte carlo (approximating expectations) in a high dimensional multivariate setting?

Comment: @conjectures I would say Monte Carlo does the same as deterministic algorithm (e.g. Riemann integration) by solving deterministic problems applying probabilistic methods, specifically estimating integrals as the expectation of certain function so that this expectation converges to desired integral according to the law of large numbers.

Comment: Have you tried to integrate a nonlinear function of a multivariate distribution using standard integration techniques? E.g. when $\mathbf x \sim \mathcal N_D(\mathbf 0, \mathbf \Sigma)$ evaluate a sum of sigmoids $E[\sum_i expit(\mathbf x_i)]$.